# Warning Underflow™ in flag dialog for flag warning/ban messages

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, flag-dialog, warning

In the flag dialog, there is a warning message shown to users who recently had flags declined or are currently subject to a flag ban. Unfortunately, it looks like a recent CSS change caused the notice to <s>overflow</s> underflow onto the left side of the dialog:

> [image: Warning notice underflows]

Can this please be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

The underflow has been fixed, but it looks like that change had another flaw which I outlined here: [Give the "some of your recent flags have been declined" banner some room](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347757/295232)

[image]