# Give the "some of your recent flags have been declined" banner some room

Tags: feature-request, design, declined-flags, flag-dialog, whitespace

The "some of your recent flags have been declined" message recently got a banner, which makes it stand out  more (which is nice) but it touches the 'Flag' button, which is less nice. Can it have some margin at the bottom (and perhaps less padding?)

[image]

Tested in the latest Safari and Firefox on macOS Catalina.