# Text not vertically centered in recent flag declined banner

Tags: bug, design, flags, declined-flags, flag-dialog

I noticed that unlike many of the elements across SE the text in the "recent flag declined" banner isn't vertically centered inside the box.

Notice the text is above a centered line, instead of the text itself being vertically centered. This causes the empty space below to be much larger than the empty space above.

[image: banner in review queue]

I tried it using responsive design with a smaller resolution and the text inside the banner also looks unbalanced.

[image: banner in review queue in a smaller resolution]

There's been a separate post about [the spacing of the banner itself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347757).